# Maven Jboss Repository Issue

Tags: maven-3

I am using Maven3 for my project i am getting a weird issue , I dont know but it is searching **CGLIB** and giving this exception...

> Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException:
>   Could not transfer artifact cglib-nodep:cglib-nodep:pom:2.1_3 from/to
>   jboss (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2): Access denied to:
>   http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/cglib-nodep/cglib-nodep/2.1_3/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.pom,
>   ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.   at
>   org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:281)
>     ... 37 more

I do not know why it searching **cglib** in Jboss repository while i do not defined any such repository in my pom.xml filr. Can anyone have idea while it going to Jboss repository?

**OutPut of mvn -X compile command**

> > Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 14:14:56+0530) Maven home: C:\Java\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin.. Java version: 1.6.0_37, vendor: Sun
> >     Microsystems Inc. Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\jre
> >     Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252 OS name: "windows 7",
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Reactor Build Order: [INFO]  [INFO] AMANDA Platform [INFO]
>   AMANDA Core API [INFO] AMANDA Shared API [INFO] AMANDA Web Application
>   [INFO] AMANDA WebServices [INFO] AMANDA WebServices Client [INFO] Pdf
>   Markup Tool [INFO] AMANDA Tomcat Installer [DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD
>   PLAN ================================================ [DEBUG] Project:
>   com.csdcsystems:amanda:pom:7.0.0.0 [DEBUG] Tasks:   [compile] [DEBUG]
>   Style:   Regular [DEBUG]
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------------- [DEBUG] Project: com.csdcsystems:amanda-core:jar:7.0.0.0 [DEBUG]
>   Tasks:   [compile] [DEBUG] Style:   Regular [DEBUG]
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------------- [DEBUG] Project: com.csdcsystems:amanda-shared:jar:7.0.0.0 [DEBUG]
>   Tasks:   [compile] [DEBUG] Style:   Regular [DEBUG]
>
> ================================================ [DEBUG] Project:       com.csdcsystems:amanda-core:7.0.0.0 [DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
>   [DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): [compile] [DEBUG] Repositories
>   (dependencies): [central
>   (https://amandai.csdcsystems.com/artifactory/libs-release, releases),
>   snapshots (https://amandai.csdcsystems.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot,
>   releases+snapshots), JBoss
>   (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/,
>   releases+snapshots)] [DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [central
>   (https://amandai.csdcsystems.com/artifactory/plugins-release,
>   releases), snapshots
>   (https://amandai.csdcsystems.com/artifactory/plugins-snapshot,
>   releases+snapshots)] [DEBUG]
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------------- [DEBUG] Goal:
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources
>   (default-resources) [DEBUG] Style:         Regular [DEBUG]
>   Configuration:   
>      ${encoding}
>   ${maven.resources.escapeString}
>   ${maven.resources.escapeWindowsPaths}
>   ${maven.resources.includeEmptyDirs}
>   
>   ${maven.resources.overwrite}
>            ${maven.resources.supportMultiLineFiltering}
>        [DEBUG]
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------------- [DEBUG] Goal:
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile
>   (default-compile) [DEBUG] Style:         Regular [DEBUG]
>   Configuration:   
>         
>   
>   ${maven.compiler.compilerId}
>   ${maven.compiler.compilerReuseStrategy}
>   ${maven.compiler.compilerVersion}
>   ${maven.compiler.debug}
>   ${maven.compiler.debuglevel}   ${encoding}
>   ${maven.compiler.executable}   ${maven.compiler.failOnError}
>   ${maven.compiler.forceJavacCompilerUse}
>   ${maven.compiler.fork}
>   
>   ${maven.compiler.maxmem}
>   ${maven.compiler.meminitial}
>   ${mojoExecution}   ${maven.compiler.optimize}
>   
>   
>   ${maven.compiler.showDeprecation}
>   ${maven.compiler.showWarnings}
>   ${maven.compiler.skipMultiThreadWarning}
>   1.6   ${lastModGranularityMs}   1.6   ${maven.compiler.verbose}
>        [DEBUG]
>   ======================================================================= [DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for
>   http://repository.jboss.com/maven2 Downloading:
>   http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/cglib-nodep/cglib-nodep/2.1_3/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.pom
>
> [DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file
>   C:\Users\sjoshi.m2\repository\cglib-nodep\cglib-nodep\2.1_3\cglib-nodep-2.1_3.pom.lastUpdated
>   [DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for
>   http://repository.jboss.com/maven2 Downloading:
>   http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/jboss/jboss-jee/4.2.0.GA/jboss-jee-4.2.0.GA.pom
>
> [DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file
>   C:\Users\sjoshi.m2\repository\jboss\jboss-jee\4.2.0.GA\jboss-jee-4.2.0.GA.pom.lastUpdated
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Reactor Summary: [INFO]  [INFO] AMANDA Platform
>   ................................... SUCCESS [0.000s] [INFO] AMANDA
>   Core API ................................... FAILURE [3.521s] [INFO]
>   AMANDA Shared API ................................. SKIPPED [INFO]
>   AMANDA Web Application ............................ SKIPPED [INFO]
>   AMANDA WebServices ................................ SKIPPED [INFO]
>   AMANDA WebServices Client ......................... SKIPPED [INFO] Pdf
>   Markup Tool ................................... SKIPPED [INFO] AMANDA
>   Tomcat Installer ........................... SKIPPED [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 3.826s [INFO] Finished at: Thu Feb 14 11:11:29 IST
>   2013 [INFO] Final Memory: 5M/73M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project amanda-core: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   com.csdcsystems:amanda-core:jar:7.0.0.0: Failed to collect
>   dependencies for [javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1 (compile),
>   commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3 (compile),
>   commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.7 (compile),
>   commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1 (compile),
>
> com.moneris:payment-moneris:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.cybersource:payment-cybsclients:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.cybersource:payment-cybssecurity:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5 (provided),
>   javax.servlet:jsp-api:jar:2.1 (provided), junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
>   (test)]   at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:258)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException:
>   Could not resolve dependencies for project
>   com.csdcsystems:amanda-core:jar:7.0.0.0: Failed to collect
>   dependencies for [javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1 (compile),
>   commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.3 (compile),
>   commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.7 (compile),
>   commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1 (compile),
>   commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.9 (compile),
>   commons-discovery:commons-discovery:jar:0.5 (compile),
>   commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.2 (compile),
>   commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4 (compile),
>   commons-jexl:commons-jexl:jar:1.1 (compile),
>   commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6 (compile),
>   commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1 (compile),
>   commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1 (compile),
>   org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.1 (compile),
>   org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.2.2 (compile),
>   oro:oro:jar:2.0.8 (compile), xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1 (compile),
>   xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.10.0 (compile), xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2
>   (compile), org.apache.axis:axis:jar:1.4 (compile),
>   log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17 (compile),
>   org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.6.7 (compile),
>   org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.8 (compile), org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.8
>   (compile), com.aspose:aspose-words:jar:10.4.0.0 (compile),
>   com.aspose:aspose-pdf-kit:jar:3.8.0 (compile),
>   bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:jar:140 (compile),
>   bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk15:jar:140 (compile),
>   org.xhtmlrenderer:core-renderer:jar:R8 (compile),
>   net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:jar:1.0.6 (compile),
>   com.lowagie:itext:jar:1.4.8 (compile), javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.5
>   (compile), jcifs:jcifs:jar:1.3.17 (compile),
>   com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3.0 (compile),
>   com.microsoft.jdbc:sqljdbc4:jar:4.0 (compile),
>   net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:jar:jdk15:2.4 (compile),
>   com.mockrunner:mockrunner-jdk1.5-j2ee1.3:jar:0.4 (compile),
>   org.opensaml:opensaml1:jar:1.1 (compile),
>   javax.xml.soap:saaj-api:jar:1.3.4 (compile), wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2
>   (compile), xpp3:xpp3:jar:1.1.4c (compile),
>   org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.5.2 (compile),
>   taglibs:standard:jar:1.1.2 (compile),
>   gudusoft.gsqlparser:gsp:jar:1.4.3.9 (compile),
>   jgroups:jgroups-all:jar:2.4.1 (compile),
>   com.sun.xml.stream:sjsxp:jar:1.0.2 (compile),
>   javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:jar:1.1 (compile), javax.media:jai_core:jar:1.1.3
>   (compile), com.sun.media:jai_imageio:jar:1.1 (compile),
>   javax.media:jai_codec:jar:1.1.3 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.sdks:CrystalCommon2:jar:12.2.213 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.sdks:QueryBuilder:jar:12.2.213 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.sdks:XMLConnector:jar:12.2.213 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.sdks:com.azalea.ufl.barcode:jar:12.2.213
>   (compile), com.businessobjects.sdks:crystal-merged:jar:12.2.213
>   (compile), com.businessobjects.sdks:cvom:jar:12.2.213 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.sdks:icu4j:jar:12.2.213 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.sdks:jrcerom:jar:12.2.213 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.sdks:keycodeDecoder:jar:12.2.213 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.sdks:logging:jar:12.2.213 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.sdks:pfjgraphics:jar:12.2.213 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.sdks:webreporting:jar:12.2.213 (compile),
>   com.gnostice:pdfone:jar:5.0.0.79 (compile),
>   com.independentsoft:exchange-server:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   org.alfresco:alfresco-web-service-client:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.oracle.xmlns:oracle-bi-ws:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   oracle.charts:oracle-chartbuilder:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.rsa:rsa-authapi:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.keyoti:RapidSpellWeb:jar:3.0.2 (compile),
>   com.keyoti:RapidSpellMDict:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   javax.ejb:ejb-api:jar:3.0 (compile), com.cognos:cognos-axis:jar:8.0
>   (compile), com.cognos:cognos-client:jar:8.0 (compile),
>   com.cognos:cognos_cam_aaa_custom:jar:8.0 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.cms:cecore:jar:2011 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.cms:celib:jar:2011 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.cms:cesession:jar:2011 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.cms:cmslogon:jar:2011 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.cms:corbaidl:jar:2011 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.cms:ebus405:jar:2011 (compile),
>   paypal.payflow:payment_paypal:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.verisign:payment_verisign:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   usbankclient:payment-usbankclient:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.exact:payment-exact:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.okgov:payment-okgov:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.moneris:payment-moneris:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.cybersource:payment-cybsclients:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.cybersource:payment-cybssecurity:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5 (provided),
>   javax.servlet:jsp-api:jar:2.1 (provided), junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
>   (test)]   at
>   org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:158)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:185)
>     ... 22 more Caused by:
>   org.sonatype.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed
>
> (compile), com.businessobjects.sdks:cvom:jar:12.2.213 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.sdks:icu4j:jar:12.2.213 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.sdks:jrcerom:jar:12.2.213 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.sdks:keycodeDecoder:jar:12.2.213 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.sdks:logging:jar:12.2.213 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.sdks:pfjgraphics:jar:12.2.213 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.sdks:webreporting:jar:12.2.213 (compile),
>   com.gnostice:pdfone:jar:5.0.0.79 (compile),
>   com.independentsoft:exchange-server:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   org.alfresco:alfresco-web-service-client:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.oracle.xmlns:oracle-bi-ws:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   oracle.charts:oracle-chartbuilder:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.rsa:rsa-authapi:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.keyoti:RapidSpellWeb:jar:3.0.2 (compile),
>   com.keyoti:RapidSpellMDict:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   javax.ejb:ejb-api:jar:3.0 (compile), com.cognos:cognos-axis:jar:8.0
>   (compile), com.cognos:cognos-client:jar:8.0 (compile),
>   com.cognos:cognos_cam_aaa_custom:jar:8.0 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.cms:cecore:jar:2011 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.cms:celib:jar:2011 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.cms:cesession:jar:2011 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.cms:cmslogon:jar:2011 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.cms:corbaidl:jar:2011 (compile),
>   com.businessobjects.cms:ebus405:jar:2011 (compile),
>   paypal.payflow:payment_paypal:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.verisign:payment_verisign:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   usbankclient:payment-usbankclient:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.exact:payment-exact:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.okgov:payment-okgov:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.moneris:payment-moneris:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.cybersource:payment-cybsclients:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   com.cybersource:payment-cybssecurity:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5 (provided),
>   javax.servlet:jsp-api:jar:2.1 (provided), junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
>   (test)]   at
>   org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:258)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:308)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:150)
>     ... 23 more Caused by:
>   org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to
>   read artifact descriptor for cglib-nodep:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3    at
>   org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:296)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:186)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:412)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:544)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:240)
>     ... 25 more Caused by:
>   org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not
>   transfer artifact cglib-nodep:cglib-nodep:pom:2.1_3 from/to jboss
>   (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2): Access denied to:
>   http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/cglib-nodep/cglib-nodep/2.1_3/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.pom,
>   ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.   at
>   org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:281)
>     ... 29 more Caused by:
>   org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not
>   transfer artifact cglib-nodep:cglib-nodep:pom:2.1_3 from/to jboss
>   (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2): Access denied to:
>   http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/cglib-nodep/cglib-nodep/2.1_3/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.pom,
>   ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.   at
>   org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:951)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:941)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:669)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) Caused by:
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Access
>   denied to:
>   http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/cglib-nodep/cglib-nodep/2.1_3/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.pom,
>   ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.   at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:835)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
>     at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
>     at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)  at
>   org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:601)
>     ... 4 more [ERROR]  [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the
>   errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
>   [ERROR]  [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the
>   build with the command [ERROR]   mvn  -rf :amanda-core

Comment: Could you add your `pom.xml` to the question? Looks like something in your pom or a parent or your `settings.xml` has that repository configured.

Comment: added the pom.xml and setting.xml

Comment: ANy one have any idea?

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with either of those files. Can you run _any_ maven commands? Does the error occur all the time?

Comment: yes when ever i am trying to run any maven command i am getting this exception

Comment: I can only suggest running `mvn -X initialize` and examining where that repository read is coming from. It has to be in there somewhere!

Comment: i have added output of that command

Comment: Is that really all the output from `mvn -X`? Can you try `mvn -X compile`. I would have expected more output from running Maven in debug mode.

Comment: Added output see question section as Stackoberflow not accept more than 30000 character so i have to delete some part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @ANdyB i found the solution i just deleted the .m2 directory from systems and then again run

> mvn eclipse:eclipse

command it run so issue with

> .m2

directory where in some place maven store repository location .

Answer (score 1):

Mock runner pom.xml refers JBoss repository hence you get the error.

[Here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/mockrunner/mockrunner-jdk1.6-j2ee1.3/0.4/mockrunner-jdk1.6-j2ee1.3-0.4.pom) you can view mock runner pom.xml. The best solution is not to use the mock runner.